# Hibernate search and JPA with JTA transaction

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I want to use the Hibernate Search full text search capabilities. I have a simple Java EE application. I annotated the entity classes and here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="library">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/webrarydb</jta-data-source>
    <class>net.hcpeter.webrary.entities.Author</class>
    <class>net.hcpeter.webrary.entities.Book</class>
    <class>net.hcpeter.webrary.entities.Request</class>
    <class>net.hcpeter.webrary.entities.User</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.indexing_strategy" value="manual"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/Users/hcpeter/Documents/workspace/indexes"/>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And I try to search this way:

```
EntityManager em = authorFacade.getEntityManager();
        FullTextEntityManager ftem = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

        ftem.getTransaction().begin();
        QueryBuilder qb = ftem.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Author.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("firsName", "lastName").matching("Author#1").createQuery();

        javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, Author.class);
        List<Author> result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        for (Author author : result) {
            System.out.println(author.getLastName() + " " + author.getFirstName());
        }
        return result;
```

Then I gave Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
So my question is how can I use hibernate Search with JTA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have jta-data-source configured (contrast to non-jta-data-source). So most likely authorFacade.getEntityManager() returns EntityManager that uses JTA-transactions. Now you have entity manager which plays with JTA transactions in your hand. You pass it as argument to getFullTextEntityManager. Likely ftem.getTransaction().begin() 
just passes call to your original (JTA) EntityManager. Then you are in problems, because getTransaction is supposed to be used only when you use application managed transactions, and one EntityManager will not play with two types of transactions.

Your options are:

1. If you are happy with JTA transactions, just use them as you use
   them elsewhere. I cannot see anything special with using
   them with Hibernate Search. If you simply don't know JTA
   transactions (and do not want to learn them now) and want about same
   transaction behavior as in your code now, annotate bean method with
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) and
   remove transaction handling from your code.
2. Configure non-jta-data-source and use it.

Comment: I want to use JTA transactions. But how can I use with lucene Queries? I need QueryBuilder when comes from EntityManager which is not FullTextEntityManager. When I try to get the fullTextEntityManager I get  `Trying to use Hibernate Search without an Hibernate EntityManager`
. And I didn't find an example so far...

Comment: So do you use some other JPA implementation than Hibernate? Which application server? I can see that you do not have provider defined in the persistence.xml, so it will be what ever is default in your application server. If you want to be sure it is is Hibernate, then you have to add <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> as described for example here: http://banana-blog.net/tag/jpa/

Comment: No I use hibernate with glassfish 3.1. I build my queries with the javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: But default in Glasshfish is EclipseLink, as told on page I linked. If you didn't defined provider, it cannot be Hibernate. You can fast check which implementation really is in use by printing out getClass() for your entity manager. If it is Hibernate, output should be like: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl

Comment: Ohh, I such an idiot... I changed my persistence.xml later and I forgot to define the provider. And I just realize some of the exceptions contains eclipselink... I'll try this way, thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, it's working! Again, thank you! You helped a lot :) The solution is: I just put it the `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` in the persistence.xml